# como obtener el id de un row de un DataTable

Tags: php, datatables

Mediante una función que busca según la selección que haga en un select estoy agregando a un `DataTable` los elementos encontrados en la busqueda. la función de agregar al `DataTable` es la siguiente:

```
function ObtenerDatosContenedorPlasmaAMover(){

        id_almacen = $('#id_almacenes option:selected').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{{ route('historicoMovimientos.ObtenerDatosContenedorPlasmaAMover') }}',
            data: {
                id_almacen: id_almacen.length ? id_almacen: null
            },

            success: function (data) {

                if ($.isEmptyObject(data.errors)) {

                    /*cant_cajas = data.plasma;*/

                    limpiarErrores();

                    $('#contenedor').empty();

                    $('#contenedor').append(data.mostrar.mostrar);

                    $('#volumen_top').text(data.mostrar.total_cajas + ' Cajas');


                    //---------------------- Aqui adiciono a las filas de datatable el plasma ----------------------

                    for(var i= 0; i < data.mostrar.cant_cajas.length; i++){

                        var rowNode = $('#datatable').DataTable().row.add( [data.mostrar.cant_cajas[i].ubicacion, data.mostrar.cant_cajas[i].estado, data.mostrar.cant_cajas[i].codigo,
                            data.mostrar.cant_cajas[i].banco, data.mostrar.cant_cajas[i].plasma, data.mostrar.cant_cajas[i].cajas, data.mostrar.cant_cajas[i].recepcion])

                                .draw(  );

                        rowNode.node().id = data.mostrar.cant_cajas[i].id;

                    }

                    /*$('#datatable').DataTable().refresh;*/

                } else {

                    limpiarErrores();

                    $.each(data.errors, function (index, value) {
                        $('#_' + index).text(value);
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

Después que agregue los elementos en la busqueda tengo que seleccionar los elementos de la tabla que quiero procesar, pero no estoy podiendo captar el `id` que le estoy asignando al `tr` y por tanto no puedo captar en la controller estos id. Estoy obteniendo los id mientras selecciono los elementos de la tabla y lo hago de esta forma:

```
$('#datatable tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {

                var tab = $('#datatable').DataTable();


                if ($(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
                    
                    eliminarArregloPlasma(tab.row(this).id());

                    $(this).removeClass('selected');

                } else {

                    $(this).toggleClass('selected');

                    var variable = {
                        'id_plasma': tab.row(this).id()
                    };

                    arreglo_plasmas.push(variable);

                    console.log(tab.row.id);
                }
                
            } );
```

En la documentación de DataTables encuentro que esta forma `tab.row(this).id()` es una solución correcta para obtener el id. Por qué no me funciona y me da `Undefined`. Debo hacer alguna otra cosa una vez que agregue la fila?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude resolver el tema con la siguiente código:

```
    $('#button').click( function () {
    
           $('#datatable tbody tr').each( function (i) {
           
               arreglo_plasmas = [];
    
               ObtenerCalculoCajas();
    
               if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
    
                   $(this).removeClass('selected');
               }
            });
     });
```

Espero que pueda ser de utilidad para alguien que presente la misma duda